# Counting total number of words in a table

Tags: python

If i have a text file, containing:

```
Alex is a footballer
Alex loves football
```

and after reading the text file into a list in python, it outputs:

```
lst = [['Alex','is','a','footballer'],['Alex','loves','football']]
```

How do i count the number of words in the list? I'm thinking of something like:

```
count = 0
for word in lst:
    count += len(lst)
```

Output:

```
Total number of words: 7
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do `sum(map(len,lst))`. More concise.

Comment: That's the perfect one, sure that OP learned plenty by asking a simple question. Happy asking.

Answer (score 2):

That works correctly if you want it to make more sense replace word with line. This is because list contains a list of lists(these smaller lists are one line of the text file).

Also if you don't want to do it in the python code, in terminal you can just write `wc -w file.txt` to see the number of words in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Another canonical way is to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and sum `1` from each element.

```
import itertools

result = sum(1 for _ in itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))
# equivalent to sum(1 for sublst in lst for el in sublst)
```

but your example code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in one line:

```
total = sum([len(i) for i in lst])
```